# Mutex for queue in mutex

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, mutex

I have to design a mutex as part of my assignment. No support from external library can be used and only system calls to de-schedule and put the thread back in ready queue are given. I am using atomic Xchg instruction to check the value of mutex. But if the mutex is unavailable I need to put the thread in a queue. Now, to again put this thread in a queue I need a mutex. Which leads me into a recursive problem. My solution is to use spin waiting here. As code for adding the thread into queue is very small, I can expect that spin waiting shouldnt be a problem. But am I missing something here ? Is there any other way than spin waiting ? Also, if I spin wait, there is no guarantee of bounded waiting. Is there a solution for that too ?

I also searched and found that in pthreads, a system call to futex is used. My assumption is that futex being a system call, its atomic in the sense of adding a thread to the queue. But here I don't have any support like this from kernel. The only system calls available to me are descheduling thread and making them runnable.

Comment: Are you trying to write correct code or optimized code? If the former, ignore the issues with bounded waiting. If the latter, you're rearranging deck chairs on the Titanic compared to the long list of much more serious issues you'd need to deal with to implement an optimized mutex.

Comment: `I can expect that spin waiting shouldnt be a problem. But am I missing something here?` With correct implementation and usage of spinlock, it should work. But you haven't provide code for check correctness.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Code is working fine. But I was curious about the design implementation, To be precise, is there a better way than spin waiting to add a thread in the queue of waiting threads for mutex ?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Alright. And what about if there is any better approach than spin waiting ? Because I just want to make sure I am not wasting CPU cycles here. I mean, we can use one synchronization primitive inside other, but at last, recursively, there has to a small amount of spin waiting at the root. Right ? Assume disabling interrupts is not an option.

Comment: `is there a better way than ...` - What are **creteria** which defines relation "better"? Perfomance? It depends on OS, architecture, programming language, workload and so on. But again, you haven't provide anything in this list. There are *lock-free* algorithms, but their applicance depends from many factors. Note, that Stack Overflow is **Question-Answer** cite, not a forum for *discussion*. Currently formulated your question is **too broad** for answering it. See also [help/dont-ask].

Comment: @user2409061 There doesn't have to be. There can be atomic operations at the root.